# Powershell Core Script only running inside pwsh command

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, invoke-webrequest

I have developed a Module "XPTO.psm1" that I created my custom class:

```
class XPTO {

                [string]$baseurl
                [string]$fileToken
                $session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
```

In my main script SCRIPT.ps1 I use:

```
#! /usr/bin/pwsh

Using module '/root/scripts/XPTO.psm1'
```

Then When I run the command "pwsh" and call the script everything works:

```
[root@XXXXXXXX scripts]# pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /root/scripts> ./SCRIPT.ps1
True                                                                                
Collecting metrics                                                                  
10/15/19 4:41:57 PM  - Starting collecting metrics from  762 applications               
10/15/19 4:41:57 PM  - Started Multithread
```

But if I run outside the pwsh it doesn't work, I receive this error:

```
[root@XXXXXXXXX scripts]# pwsh ./SCRIPT.ps1
At /root/scripts/XPTO.psm1:198 char:17
+ ...   $session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession].
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (/root/scripts/scrip\u2026ts/XPTO.psm1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Comment: for ps5.1, there is a `$env:PSModulePath` that powershell.exe uses to find the various modules. do you have the modules in your path somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Powershell will throw this error the first time you instantiate a new empty WebRequestSession instead of having one created as the result of parameterizing the session var in Invoke-WebRequest.

I created a 2 line script called `session.ps1` to test:

```
$session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
Write-Host $session.UserAgent
```

When I run this the first time, it gives me the same error. However, all I do is run it again, and the error doesn't occur.

```
C:\Users\nick\Desktop>pwsh session.ps1
Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession].
At C:\Users\nick\Desktop\session.ps1:1 char:12
+ $session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...bRequestSession:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

C:\Users\nick\Desktop>pwsh session.ps1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299; en-US) PowerShell/6.1.3
```

So it seems like maybe you're creating a new WebRequestSession in a way that wasn't intended? Not sure the best way around the issue, but I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with your module.